# What is the use of response.js

Tags: javascript

What is the **use** of response.js.
What are **breakpoints** in response.js.
Can anyone provide links for tutorial for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Response is an experimental jQuery plugin for building websites with responsive content. It can dynamically swap content based on breakpoints and data attributes.

a complete explaination about the plugin with the Breakpoint Sets can be found on: 
[http://responsejs.com](http://responsejs.com/)